# How to calculate hour value from degree?

Tags: objective-c

```
0 Degree = 3 o'clock
90 Degree = 0 o'clock
180 Degree = 9 0 o'clock
```

so can we have a expression to convert from Degree to clock hour in objective-C?

Comment: Sure you can.  This is really a basic math question.  What have you tried to do so far?  Show your code.

Comment: I tried to calculate the radians from degree first and then shift 3. But some case it's not correct

Comment: you can show the tried code and output as well.

Comment: hour = degree / 30 - 3;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very basic maths problem.

```
degrees = ((3 - hour) % 12) * 30
```

- When hour = 3 => 0
- When hour = 9 => 180
- When hour = 6 => 270
- When hour = 0 => 90

To get the hour just reverse the problem...

```
(-degrees / 30 + 3) % 12 = hour
```

You can try this [on Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(-x%2F+30+%2B+3)+mod+12+for+x%3D+175.030258)

Comment: I want to get hour from degree, I mean I have the degree :D

Comment: (-degrees / 30) % 12 + 3 = hour
if degrees = 175.030258

so the hour will be - 2

Comment: @0x686169 no http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(-175.030258+%2F+30)+mod+12+%2B+3

Comment: @0x686169 moved the mod function to the end. It didn't make sense to have it where it was. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(-175.030258+%2F+30+%2B+3)+mod+12

Comment: I'm trying to fix my implementation code.
Could you give me the expression to calculate minute from degree.
Thank a million!

Comment: @0x686169 this is exactly the same problem. You should be able to create a formula for calculating the minute from the formula above. You need to change 3 values in it. Hint: 30 = the number of degrees for 1 hour. 12 = the number of hours in 360 degrees. 3 is the number of hours from 3 (0 degrees) to pointing straight upwards.

Comment: NSLog(@"hour : %d", ((int)-8.50228595) % 12);
        NSLog(@"hour : %d", (int)fmod(-8.50228595, 12));
        NSLog(@"hour : %d", (int)fmodf(-8.50228595, 12));

Result = -8
f Apple

Comment: @0x686169 I don't know what this means?

Comment: Thanks @Fogmeister, Cound you do me a favor help me calculate Degree from Hour and Min.

Comment: @0x686169 it is there already. You should be able to do this.

Comment: Thank you very much! I did fixed it by myself.

Comment: @0x686169 excellent good work :) isn't it satisfying when you do :-)